# How to highlight/grey-out Tabcontrol Tabpage

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have an application on which only certain Tabs are selectable based on choices user make.
How can I can grey-out those unselectable tab(s) on a windows forms application.

Comment: have you tried just setting their Enabled propety (or client enabled) to false in the code behind?

Comment: This is Blooper #4 in [this book](http://www.amazon.com/GUI-Bloopers-2-0-Second-Technologies/dp/0123706432/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1409158261&sr=8-1&keywords=gui+bloopers+2.0), strongly recommended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To grey them out I guess you'll have to owner-draw the tabs.

The Enabled property is not well supported; you can see that by its **not even being included in Intellisense**. You can and should still set it but it will only paint the Background grey, neither will it paint the Tabs nor will it disable any controls or prevent the user from selecting the tab. (Not sure if that's such a good UI design anyway..You may want to set at least a toolTip to explain why the page can't be accessed. Or you let it be selected and disable all controls on it recursively.. Or you do as you please ;-)

To make them unselectable simply put this into the `tabControl1_Selecting` event:

```
if (!e.TabPage.Enabled)  e.Cancel = true;
```

To ownerdraw the Tabs set `DrawMode` to e.g. `OwnerDrawFixed` put some painting code like this into the `DrawItem` event:

```
private void tabControl1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    TabPage tp = tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index];
   using (SolidBrush brush = 
          new SolidBrush(tp.Enabled ? tp.BackColor : SystemColors.ControlLight))
   using (SolidBrush textBrush = 
          new SolidBrush(tp.Enabled ? tp.ForeColor : SystemColors.ControlDark))
    {
       e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.Bounds);
       e.Graphics.DrawString(tp.Text, e.Font, textBrush, e.Bounds.X + 3, e.Bounds.Y + 4);
    }
}
```

I have decided to also paint the active Tabs in the color of their pages, as I feel it should be; you can change the 1st brush color to `tabControl1.BackColor`, if you want to.
The Systemcolors I chose may not always be the best, but you get the idea, I hope..