# How can I disable (grey out) specific tabpage(s) of a tab control programatically in my C# form app?

Tags: c#, tabcontrol, tabpage

I can't believe that disabling specific tabpages (visible but greyed out that means not clickable) is not possible in Visual Studio C# Form app. I have found just a workaround that I couldn't bring to work.(See link below)
I wanted to ask this question again, because perhaps there is another solution/workaround in the meantime.
[How to highlight/grey-out Tabcontrol Tabpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25529261/how-to-highlight-grey-out-tabcontrol-tabpage)

For just making the tab nonclickable (what is also OK for me) I have used this code, but not working

```
 private void tabControl1_Selecting(object sender,TabControlCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.TabPage.Enabled)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Winforms is just a wrapper around the build in UI implemented in Windows. It was created for Win95 with the intention of a systemwide consistent Look&Feel. And i assume in that Look&Feel a unusable TabPage should simply not be visible. If you want something your way (understandable) seeing from today's standards then don't use yesterdays technology.

Comment: The TabControl is known for being unruly. Create your own TabControl, you'll have full control over everything. If you want a more modern UI, go for WPF, if you want to fully customize your controls and UI go for Windows Forms.
A TabPage which is not enabled already is non clickable. The code above does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example if you want to disable tabPage2 use this code in form load event. It will not show in intellisense but you can type.

```
tabPage2.Enabled = false;
```

Then use tab control selecting event like this

```
private void tabControl1_Selecting(object sender, TabControlCancelEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.TabPageIndex < 0) return;
   e.Cancel = !e.TabPage.Enabled;
}
```

Comment: Thank tou so much!!! With your easy explanation I got it, and worked fine. You helped me so much :-)